# Error when Project.yaml Migration from Local

Tags: migration, craft4

I'm getting the following error when migrating the project folder over to my live environment. Never had this before and unsure what to do.

```
error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'gifdb.stc_18_button' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `stc_18_button` ADD `field_buttonLink_golezhqt` text
```

Things I've tried:

- Rebuilding the Config on my Local
- Restoring the DB and Trying Again

Still get this error.

Could this be down to the latest update and supertable? Or both?

Both Craft CMS 4.4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a supertable setup, if I'm not mistaken. If you go to the settings menu for the Supertable plugin (assuming you have it installed) there should be some push button tools for fixing/cleaning up the database. Give those a try

Comment: Lifesaver. Thank you.